# Code to configure free SSL in .net core and aws

Tags: asp.net-core, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, asp.net-core-3.1

I have a .net core Web API Angular application which I have deployed on AWS Elastic Beans (Linux) with the help of AWS Toolkit for Visual Studio. AWS Container Type is **64bit Amazon Linux 2 v2.0.2 running .NET Core**.

My project requirement is to run the application on https with the help of the **letsencrypt**. Can someone please guide me with some reference how I can configure my application to run on https when deployed on nginx server on AWS Elastic Beans.

I am beginner to AWS and Linux and any help will be appreciated.

Comment: AWS prodivide such [guides](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elastic-beanstalk-https-configuration/). Have you checked them?

Comment: Thank you @Marcin for response, while following [this](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elastic-beanstalk-https-configuration/) I did not see an option without the load balancer, We are not using the load balancer since our application is very small and its POC kind of but we need https to enable the video calling